Structure moves in the MD simulation with LAMMPS
I am doing the classic molecular dynamic simulation with LAMMPS. The whole structure is the bilayer graphene sandwiched by Al2O3 on both side. I want to study how the thermal conductance changes with the distance between the bilayer graphene.
This is my input file.
variable         kb equal 8.617333262e-5
variable         t equal 300.0
variable         th equal 400.0
variable         tc equal 200.0

units            metal
dimension        3
newton           on
boundary         p p p
atom_style       charge
neighbor         2.0 bin
timestep         0.0005

read_data        atomic_structure_atomic

pair_style        hybrid comb3 polar_off lj/cut 12.0 airebo 3.0
pair_coeff       * * comb3 ./ffield.comb3.NiAlO O Al NULL NULL
pair_coeff       * * airebo ./CH.airebo NULL NULL C C
pair_coeff       1 3 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 4 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       2 3 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 4 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846

compute          ke1 all ke/atom
variable         tem atom c_ke1/1.5/${kb}

thermo           1000
thermo_style     custom step temp pxx pyy pzz press vol
velocity         all create $t 898758 mom yes rot yes dist gaussian

min_style        cg
minimize         1.0e-8 1.0e-8 1000000 1000000

#1st euqilibrium in NPT ensamble
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom step temp pe ke etotal vol pxx pyy pzz press
fix              1 all npt temp $t $t 0.05 aniso 0.0 0.0 0.5
dump             xyz_npt all xyz 1000 dump_npt.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_npt element O Al C1 C2
run              500000
unfix            1
undump           xyz_npt
reset_timestep   0
write_data       output_npt.dat

#2nd equilibrium in NVT ensamble
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom temp pe ke etotal vol pxx pyy pzz press
fix              2 all nvt temp $t $t 0.05
dump             xyz_nvt all xyz 1000 dump_nvt.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_nvt element O Al C1 C2
run              500000
unfix            2
undump           xyz_nvt
reset_timestep   0

#Dividing the zone
variable         zbl equal zlo
variable         zbh equal zhi
variable         nla equal 100
variable         sca equal 1/${nla}
variable         len equal ${zbh}-${zbl}
variable         dz equal ${len}/${nla}
variable         zll equal ${zbl}+${dz}*2
variable         zlh equal ${zbl}+${dz}*6
variable         zrl equal ${zbh}-${dz}*6
variable         zrh equal ${zbh}-${dz}*2

region           reg_whole block INF INF INF INF ${zbl} ${zbh} units box
region           lef_fixed block INF INF INF INF INF ${zll} units box
region           hot block INF INF INF INF ${zll} ${zlh} units box
region           cold block INF INF INF INF ${zrl} ${zrh} units box
region           rig_fixed block INF INF INF INF ${zrh} INF units box
region           fixed_both union 2 lef_fixed rig_fixed

group            fixed region fixed_both
group            hot region hot
group            cold region cold
group            move subtract all fixed

reset_timestep   0
change_box       all boundary p p f

velocity         fixed set 0 0 0
fix              fixed fixed setforce 0 0 0

fix              3 hot langevin ${th} ${th} 0.05 14565 tally yes
fix              4 cold langevin ${tc} ${tc} 0.05 16576 tally yes
fix              5 all nve

variable         time equal step
variable         el equal f_3
variable         er equal f_4

compute          6 all chunk/atom bin/1d z lower ${sca} units reduced
fix              7 all ave/chunk 1 10000 10000 6 v_tem file profile.heat
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom step temp ke pe etotal press vol
dump             xyz_nve all xyz 1000 dump_nve.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_nve element O Al C1 C2
run              500000
unfix            7
undump           xyz_nve
reset_timestep   0

fix              8 all ave/chunk 1 10000 10000 6 v_tem file time_average_temperature.dat
fix              eou all print 2000 "${time} ${el} ${er}" file energy.dat title "time e1 e2" screen no

thermo           20000
thermo_style     custom step temp ke pe etotal press vol
dump             fin all xyz 20000 fin.xyz
dump_modify      fin element O Al C1 C2
run              500000

I found that the graphene sheet moves after the structure relaxation in the NPT ensemble. This is means that the distance between the bilayer graphene changes and it is impossible to obtain the relation between the thermal conductance and the interlayer spacing.
Would anyone please tell me how to fix the graphene sheet position so as to obtain the relation between the interlayer spacing and the thermal conductance?
Can I do the thermal conductance calculation without the structure relaxation in the NPT and NVT ensembles? Does it make sense?
And suggestion is appreciated.
